# Unable to findElement using xpath or css in SeleniumWebdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to find an element in a webpage.I tried finding it using xpath and cssSelector but I am getting an exception "No such Element Found"

I opened the page 2-3 times and xpath is not changing.Please suggest how to locate this element using selenium webdriver.

```
<div class="breadcrumb-container breadcrumb-text-last edit-mode" title="Campaign Analytics (DSP)">Campaign Analytics (...</div>
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite unclear what is the issue here, but, given what is provided in the question, here are the XPath expressions that should match your element:

```
//div[@title = 'Campaign Analytics (DSP)']
//div[starts-with(., 'Campaign Analytics')]
```

Additionally, check that element is not inside an `iframe` - if yes, switch to the `iframe` before searching the element. Another possible problem is the timing one - the element is not yet present/loaded when you perform the search - in this case you would need to add an Explicit Wait.